# PyQtGraph: why the object is always at the left-bottom corner

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class Demo(gl.GLViewWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()
        xgrid = gl.GLGridItem()
        ygrid = gl.GLGridItem()
        zgrid = gl.GLGridItem()

        xgrid.rotate(90, 0, 1, 0)
        ygrid.rotate(90, 1, 0, 0)

        xgrid.scale(0.2, 0.1, 0.1)
        ygrid.scale(0.2, 0.1, 0.1)
        zgrid.scale(0.1, 0.2, 0.1)

        self.addItem(xgrid)
        self.addItem(ygrid)
        self.addItem(zgrid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After running the code, you can see that the 3d object is always at the left-bottom corner of the whole widget.
[image]

I've check the source code of PyQtGraph but don't know which is the right function to change the position.

Any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: In my case with Linux and pyqtgraph==0.10.0 the element is placed in the center of the widget https://imgur.com/a/pqH6PB0

Comment: Mine is also 0.10.0. I just ran it on Windows. It's also placed in the center. Why Mac is different. That's strange...so what would you do if you want to change the object's position? Is there any function available?

Comment: Hi, are you running on a Macbook with a scaled retina display? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem, found a question related to it on [github](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/785)

Installing the development branch of PyQtGraph with `pip install git+https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph@develop` resolved it for me